# Proof that if $a$ is an integer greater than $1,$ then there are infinitely many primes of the form $p=a^n(a+1)-1,$ where $n$ is a positive integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm trying to prove the following proposition:

> If $a$ is an integer greater than $1$ then there are infinitely many primes $p$ of the form $$p=a^n(a+1)-1, $$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

I really don't know how to proceed...

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Noone knows how to proceed because for every $a>1$ this is an open problem!
Don't feel dissapointed.
We know that the only non trivial sequence of numbers which yield infinitely many primes is the arithmetic progression $a+bn$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$
and this is called [Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)

**Source**:An Introduction to the Theory of numbers ,Hardy & Wright,Fifth edition,page 18.

Comment: can you provide a source  please?